# How to use setOnItemClickListener() on @android:id/list

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Tried many solutions, but cannot use the setOnItemClickListener() in the example given in the following link 
http://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/android-listview-alphabet-scroller

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still facing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

this is how i got my setOnItemClickListener working:

```
    private ListView myList;

    myList= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);

    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // DO SOME ACTION
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still facing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to directly override the method `onListItemClick()` since the link you given is extending the `ListActivity`

You should have a look on the docs-
The Super class ListActivity is having the `protected` method~-

```
    /**
     * This method will be called when an item in the list is selected.
     * Subclasses should override. Subclasses can call
     * getListView().getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the
     * data associated with the selected item.
     *
     * @param l The ListView where the click happened
     * @param v The view that was clicked within the ListView
     * @param position The position of the view in the list
     * @param id The row id of the item that was clicked
     */
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    }
```

Comment: Yes you got that right, I completely missed out the method onListItemClick(),but still the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

when you use the onListItemClick() method, in xml file for ListView, you must give this id to ListView:

> @android:id/list